# May I attempt to draw someone's attention?

Tags: discussion

What can I do if I want to draw someone's attention to a post? For example on the comments [on this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14447/1172); someone else was dealing with the same issue, and I wanted a second read on the Mishnah Berura. Would that be considered inappropriate? Should I just let the comment be (or delete the answer since I doubted *my* reading)? If the answers is no, it is not inappropriate, what would be a good way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

If the user was recently active in [the site's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468), then you can type a [commercial at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_at) and the start of his name (e.g., for me, `@ms`) and the software will offer you his name as the rest; if that occurs, then the user was in chat recently enough that typing that (the commercial at and his name) will notify him that someone wants to chat with him there.

Note, though, that people's names on `chat.stackexchange.com` aren't always the same as their names on `judaism.stackexchange.com`.